# Copy tabs/sheets from one workbook to another with macro/vba code (1 button)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

two (hopefully) easy questions -

1. Can I copy 2 tabs from File1.xlsm to a master.XLSX file and still run the macro code?  I assume not?
2. Assuming I cannot do #1, can I copy the 2 tabs into another master.xlsm file?  If so, please help I've tried the following.

File1.xlsm just has a grid with a 1 button that calls 'File1.xlsm'!getData which populates the grid.

I was able to right click the tabs in File1.xlsm and move/copy them successfully into master.xlsm but without the vba getData Sub(). When I click the button it said it couldn't find the !getData code.  Is there a clean way to copy the 2 tabs, and !getData macro code into the Master.xlsm?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: If you put the macro code in the sheet code module then it will move along with the sheet. Use an ActiveX button though, not a Forms one (or when you copy the sheet, the Forms button still points back to the previous version)

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this task, you should consider adding the relevant code into a module within your File1 workbook. You will need to enable the Visual Basic extensibility within your File1 workbook library.

You would then need to copy the module along with the two sheets into the new workbook. You would do this with commands similar to the following.

```
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("module1").Export Path
SomeWorkbook.VBE.VBProject.VBComponents.Import Path
```

Where path is a string variable to a place where you would like to place the module, and someworkbook would be your Master.xlsm workbook object.

Answer (score 0):

```
with ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
  .VBComponents("sheet1").codemodule.addfromstring   .VBComponents("Sheet1").codemodule.lines(1,.VBComponents("Module1").codemodule.CountofLines)
end with
sheets(array("sheet1","sheet2")).copy
```